# Query posts filtered by post_object custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am trying to query any post which has a certain post_object selected as its "parent". The parent value will have to match the ID of the current post. I have been able to replicate this functionality by querying all posts of this post type and then comparing the values within the loop, like so:

```
<?php
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query(  array (
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'meta_key'=>'post_object_field'
)); 

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php 
    $parent = get_field('post_object_field'); 
    $parentId = $parent->ID; ?>

    <?php if ($postId == $parentId): ?>

        // content 

    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I'm wonder if there is a way to check for this value inside the query, and if so, if it's any faster or more correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all the posts/pages that are children of a given post/page, you can use the parameter [**post_parent**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters), using the ID of the parent post.

For example, if you have a post

```
$wp_query->query(  array (
    'post_type'    => $children_post_type
    'post_parent'  => $postId
));
```

And of course, yes, performing a query will be much more efficient than performing a query + getting a field value + creating a variable + looping the results making a comparison...

---

***EDIT***: According to your comments, it seems that you're actually trying to get all those posts that have a given value in a custom field of type *Post Object*. This field contains a number, which is the ID of the post it relates to, so you just need to add a parameter [**meta_value_num**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in your query:

```
$wp_query->query(  array (
    'post_type'      => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_key'       => 'post_object_field'
    'meta_value_num' => $postId
));
```

This will retrieve all the posts that have a custom field called `post_object_field` with a value `$postId`.

---

***EDIT***: Try this:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'  => 'my_post_type',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key'     => 'post_object_field',
        'value'   => $postId,
        'compare' => '='
    )
)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I should have been more specific. The parent is a different post type than the child. Is there a way to assign these relationships between post types?

Comment: @johnnyd23, in the query you should use the `post_type` of the children posts! Or just don't set any `post_type` at all (like I edited). This way you'll be retrieving all the children of your parent post, regardless of their post type...

Comment: I am already querying by post type. I need to query by post type as well as a custom field value. This custom field is a post_object and the problem is I dont know how to check against the value of that post_object

Comment: @johnnyd23, so you don't want to get those posts that are children of a given post, but you want to get those posts that have a custom field with a given value, is this right?

Comment: correct, I can't assign the posts as children as they are of a different post type than their parent

Comment: @johnnyd23, see my EDIT. If that's not what you mean, consider re-writing your question, because I don't get it...

Comment: I understand how to check for a certain value, but it doesn't seem you can check for the value of a post_object field in this way.

Comment: @johnnyd23, sorry I don't know what you mean with "*post_object field*"

Comment: @johnnyd23, ok, I've re-written my EDIT. That field contains a number, which is the ID of the post_object it relates to. So you should be able to query it using `'meta_value_num' => $postId`.

Comment: This does not work. The field does not return the ID, rather the post object itself, as in https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post

Comment: @johnnyd23, the *Post Object* field "returns" a `WP_Object` if you use the `get_field()` function. But if you explore the DB table `wp_postmeta`, you´ll see that what's stored in the DB is the Id of the related post (just a number) as the value of the field. The ACF `get_field()` function uses that ID to give you a `WP_Object`, but you should be able to query using the ID! Are you **sure** you're using the correct *post_type*, *meta_key* and *meta_value_num* and the query doesn't return anything?

Comment: I'm 100% positive I'm using the right info. The query is still pulling all posts of `my_post_type` that have the `post_object_field`. Adding the `meta_value_num` doesn't change anything.

Comment: I had actually just tried that, and it worked, and posted the answer myself. I'll mark yours as correct as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: @johnnyd23, no problem! I'm not sure why you need a `meta_query`, but I'm happy you sorted it out!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query(  array (
    'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'post_object_field',
            'value' => $postId,
            'compare' => '=='
        )
     )
));
```

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

```
// content
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to filter the results within the query using:

```
<?php
    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
    $wp_query->query(  array (
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_object_field',
                'value' => $postId,
                'compare' => '=='
            )
         )
    )); 

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    // content 

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```